# Pivot table data using GROUP BY ROLLUP

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, rollup

[Note: any SQL database that supports ROLLUP can be used here. I've used BigQuery for the examples.]

I am looking to get all the data for the following PivotTable in Excel:

[image]

There should be 36 cells of data. The BigQuery query that I have so far is as follows:

```
SELECT Year, Quarter, ProductGroup, Product, SUM(Revenue) AS SumOfRevenue, SUM(Units) as SumOfUnits FROM `first-outlet-750.biengine_tutorial.Product`
WHERE Year IN (2020) and Quarter in ('Q1')
GROUP BY ROLLUP(ProductGroup, Product, Year, Quarter)
union distinct
SELECT Year, Quarter, ProductGroup, Product, SUM(Revenue) AS SumOfRevenue, SUM(Units) as SumOfUnits FROM `first-outlet-750.biengine_tutorial.Product`
WHERE Year IN (2020) and Quarter in ('Q1')
GROUP BY ROLLUP(Year, Quarter, Product, ProductGroup)
```

However, it gives me only 34 results, whereas I'm looking for 36. What would be the proper way to provide all the pivot-table combinations in this query? Data attached here:

```
$ cat > Products.csv
ProductGroup,Product,Year,Quarter,Revenue,Units,Count,Product Key,Reseller,Product Info,QuarterAsNumber
Electronics,Phone,2018,Q1,103,7,1,2018-Q1,Sony,Format=XML; <Properties>…,1
Electronics,Phone,2018,Q1,102,4,1,2018-Q1,Sony,Format=XML; <Properties>…,1
Electronics,Phone,2019,Q1,98,12,1,2019-Q1,Sony,Format=XML; <Properties>…,1
Electronics,Computer,2018,Q1,104,3,1,2018-Q1,Samsung,Format=XML; <Properties>…,1
Electronics,Computer,2019,Q1,83,7,1,2019-Q1,Google,Format=XML; <Properties>…,1
Media,Theater,2018,Q1,17,4,1,2018-Q1,Sony,Format=XML; <Properties>…,1
Media,Theater,2019,Q1,20,7,1,2019-Q1,Sony,Format=XML; <Properties>…,1
Media,Movies,2018,Q1,25,12,1,2018-Q1,Microsoft,Format=XML; <Properties>…,1
Media,Movies,2019,Q1,26,13,1,2019-Q1,Sony,Format=XML; <Properties>…,1
Electronics,Phone,2018,Q2,105,5,1,2018-Q2,Samsung,Format=XML; <Properties>…,2
Electronics,Phone,2019,Q2,82,15,1,2019-Q2,LG,Format=XML; <Properties>…,2
Electronics,Computer,2018,Q2,99,4,1,2018-Q2,LG,Format=XML; <Properties>…,2
Electronics,Computer,2019,Q2,84,20,1,2019-Q2,Sony,Format=XML; <Properties>…,2
Media,Theater,2018,Q2,17,4,1,2018-Q2,Microsoft,Format=XML; <Properties>…,2
Media,Theater,2019,Q2,22,5,1,2019-Q2,Sony,Format=XML; <Properties>…,2
Media,Movies,2018,Q2,25,12,1,2018-Q2,Samsung,Format=XML; <Properties>…,2
Media,Movies,2019,Q2,26,14,1,2019-Q2,Google,Format=XML; <Properties>…,2
Electronics,Phone,2000,Q1,103,7,1,2000-Q1,Sony,Format=XML; <Properties>…,1
Electronics,Phone,2001,Q1,102,4,1,2001-Q1,Sony,Format=XML; <Properties>…,1
Electronics,Phone,2002,Q1,98,12,1,2002-Q1,Microsoft,Format=XML; <Properties>…,1
Electronics,Computer,2003,Q1,104,3,1,2003-Q1,Sony,Format=XML; <Properties>…,1
Electronics,Computer,2004,Q1,83,7,1,2004-Q1,Samsung,Format=XML; <Properties>…,1
Media,Theater,2005,Q1,17,4,1,2005-Q1,Google,Format=XML; <Properties>…,1
Media,Theater,2006,Q1,20,7,1,2006-Q1,Sony,Format=XML; <Properties>…,1
Media,Movies,2007,Q1,25,12,1,2007-Q1,Sony,Format=XML; <Properties>…,1
Media,Movies,2008,Q1,26,13,1,2008-Q1,Microsoft,Format=XML; <Properties>…,1
Electronics,Phone,2009,Q2,105,5,1,2009-Q2,Sony,Format=XML; <Properties>…,2
Electronics,Phone,2010,Q2,82,15,1,2010-Q2,Sony,Format=XML; <Properties>…,2
Electronics,Computer,2011,Q2,99,4,1,2011-Q2,Sony,Format=XML; <Properties>…,2
Electronics,Computer,2012,Q2,84,20,1,2012-Q2,Sony,Format=XML; <Properties>…,2
Media,Theater,2013,Q2,17,4,1,2013-Q2,Sony,Format=XML; <Properties>…,2
Media,Theater,2014,Q2,22,5,1,2014-Q2,Sony,Format=XML; <Properties>…,2
Media,Movies,2015,Q2,25,12,1,2015-Q2,Sony,Format=XML; <Properties>…,2
Media,Movies,2016,Q2,26,14,1,2016-Q2,Samsung,Format=XML; <Properties>…,2
Media,Movies,2017,Q1,26,13,1,2017-Q1,Google,Format=XML; <Properties>…,1
Electronics,Phone,2018,Q2,105,5,1,2018-Q2,Sony,Format=XML; <Properties>…,2
Electronics,Phone,2019,Q2,82,15,1,2019-Q2,Sony,Format=XML; <Properties>…,2
Electronics,Computer,2020,Q2,99,4,1,2020-Q2,Microsoft,Format=XML; <Properties>…,2
Electronics,Phone,2020,Q1,103,7,1,2020-Q1,Sony,Format=XML; <Properties>…,1
Electronics,Phone,2020,Q2,102,4,1,2020-Q2,Samsung,Format=XML; <Properties>…,2
Electronics,Phone,2020,Q3,98,12,1,2020-Q3,LG,Format=XML; <Properties>…,3
Electronics,Computer,2020,Q4,104,3,1,2020-Q4,LG,Format=XML; <Properties>…,4
Electronics,Computer,2020,Q1,83,7,1,2020-Q1,Sony,Format=XML; <Properties>…,1
Media,Theater,2020,Q1,17,4,1,2020-Q1,Microsoft,Format=XML; <Properties>…,1
Media,Theater,2020,Q1,20,7,1,2020-Q1,Sony,Format=XML; <Properties>…,1
```

Here is the long-form of what I am looking for:

```
-- >, ProductGroup> 
SELECT ProductGroup, NULL, NULL, NULL, SUM(Revenue) AS SumOfRevenue, SUM(Units) as SumOfUnits FROM `first-outlet-750.biengine_tutorial.Product`
WHERE Year IN (2020) and Quarter in ('Q1')
GROUP BY ROLLUP (ProductGroup)

-- ProductGroup>Product
union distinct 
SELECT ProductGroup, Product, NULL, NULL, SUM(Revenue) AS SumOfRevenue, SUM(Units) as SumOfUnits FROM `first-outlet-750.biengine_tutorial.Product`
WHERE Year IN (2020) and Quarter in ('Q1')
GROUP BY ProductGroup, Product

-- ProductGroup>Product>Year
union distinct 
SELECT ProductGroup, Product, Year, NULL, SUM(Revenue) AS SumOfRevenue, SUM(Units) as SumOfUnits FROM `first-outlet-750.biengine_tutorial.Product`
WHERE Year IN (2020) and Quarter in ('Q1')
GROUP BY ProductGroup, Product, Year

-- ProductGroup>Year
union distinct 
SELECT ProductGroup, NULL, Year, NULL, SUM(Revenue) AS SumOfRevenue, SUM(Units) as SumOfUnits FROM `first-outlet-750.biengine_tutorial.Product`
WHERE Year IN (2020) and Quarter in ('Q1')
GROUP BY ProductGroup, Year

-- ProductGroup>Year>Quarter
union distinct 
SELECT ProductGroup, NULL, Year, Quarter, SUM(Revenue) AS SumOfRevenue, SUM(Units) as SumOfUnits FROM `first-outlet-750.biengine_tutorial.Product`
WHERE Year IN (2020) and Quarter in ('Q1')
GROUP BY ProductGroup, Year, Quarter

-- ProductGroup>Product>Year>Quarter
union distinct 
SELECT ProductGroup , Product, Year, Quarter, SUM(Revenue) AS SumOfRevenue, SUM(Units) as SumOfUnits FROM `first-outlet-750.biengine_tutorial.Product`
WHERE Year IN (2020) and Quarter in ('Q1')
GROUP BY ProductGroup, Product, Year, Quarter

-- Year>Quarter
union distinct 
SELECT NULL , NULL, Year, Quarter, SUM(Revenue) AS SumOfRevenue, SUM(Units) as SumOfUnits FROM `first-outlet-750.biengine_tutorial.Product`
WHERE Year IN (2020) and Quarter in ('Q1')
GROUP BY Year, Quarter

-- Year
union distinct 
SELECT NULL , NULL, Year, NULL, SUM(Revenue) AS SumOfRevenue, SUM(Units) as SumOfUnits FROM `first-outlet-750.biengine_tutorial.Product`
WHERE Year IN (2020) and Quarter in ('Q1')
GROUP BY Year
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BigQuery does not have Cube or Grouping Set, so below trick is what you can use - looks quite generic to me to be expanded to any dimensions while avoiding redundant lines of code

```
select 
  (case when grp_set & 1 > 0 then ProductGroup end) as ProductGroup,
  (case when grp_set & 2 > 0 then Product end) as Product,
  (case when grp_set & 4 > 0 then Year end) as Year,
  (case when grp_set & 8 > 0 then Quarter end) as Quarter,
  sum(Revenue) as Revenue,
  sum(Units) as Units    
from `first-outlet-750.biengine_tutorial.Product`, unnest(generate_array(1, 16)) grp_set
where Year IN (2020) and Quarter in ('Q1')
group by 1, 2, 3, 4
having not (Year is null and not Quarter is null)
and not (ProductGroup is null and not Product is null)
-- order by 1, 2, 3, 4
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: thanks for the response, but the numbers look wrong. For example, the "ALL" should be 223 / 25.

Comment: Number are exactly as in your query - i tested before answering! double check please on your side!

Comment: yup, my query gets 223 / 25, also what Excel gets.

Comment: i am using data sample that you provided in the question - and for all NULLS your query returns - 424/33!

Comment: same result, if I just simply do sum(revenue) and sum(units) for whole dataset. is it possible that you have data different from sample in question? just run my query against your data then!

Comment: Oh, I see where the difference - in first query - you filter by Q1 while in second (final) query you filter by Q1 and Q2. so if you remove Q2 in my query - you will get the result as in screenshot. please confirm

Comment: I see, mine is wrong then let me adjust.

Comment: what do you mean filter by Q1/Q2? I just copied in my first query. https://gyazo.com/c90770bf145d9ada40dccaf46ea0f5fd

Comment: WHERE Year IN (2020) and Quarter in ('Q1', 'Q2')

Comment: yea I deleted that, just use the first query and what it should look like from Excel -- 36 results.

Comment: so, try my answer but instead of `where Year IN (2020) and Quarter in ('Q1', 'Q2')` use `where Year IN (2020) and Quarter in ('Q1')`

Comment: i just adjusted answer to filter by Q1 only! Does this now give you expected result?! :o)

Comment: yes, thank you! By the way, is this something you think could be put well into a UDF? Maybe something like `PIVOT(rows_list, cols_list, vals_list)` ?

Comment: maybe into Table Valued Function! But I think it depends on what particular use case you have in mind. Try and if needed post new question :o)

Comment: by the way, if BQ **did** support the `CUBE` function what would the above query be instead? Is it much simpler or not really?

Comment: using `group by grouping set (<list if groups here>)` would simplify life quite a bit. just google it or search on SO - plenty of references, examples, ...