# BigQuery pivot on more fields

Tags: google-bigquery, pivot

Following up on [Pivot table data using GROUP BY ROLLUP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69804322/pivot-table-data-using-group-by-rollup/69804952#69804322), I would like to produce a pivot along the lines that Mikhail showed on a 3x3 pivot table. In Excel, it gives us 180 value cells:

[image]

It gives 128 non-empty cells, but 180 cells including empty cells (lower-right is the Count: 128, upper left is the 15Rx12C=180). Here is the query I have now which gives me 128 'value cells':

```
select 
  (case when grp_set & 1 > 0 then Reseller end) as Reseller,
  (case when grp_set & 2 > 0 then ProductGroup end) as ProductGroup,
  (case when grp_set & 4 > 0 then Product end) as Product,
  (case when grp_set & 8 > 0 then Year end) as Year,
  (case when grp_set & 16 > 0 then Quarter end) as Quarter,
  (case when grp_set & 32 > 0 then Product_Info end) as Product_Info,
  sum(Revenue) as Revenue,
  sum(Units) as Units    
from `first-outlet-750.biengine_tutorial.Product`, unnest(generate_array(1, 64)) grp_set
where Year IN (2020) and Quarter in ('Q1', 'Q2')
group by 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
having not (Quarter is null and Product_Info is not null)
and not (Year is null and Quarter is not null)
and not (Reseller is null and ProductGroup is not null)
and not (ProductGroup is null and Product is not null)
order by 1, 2, 3, 4 , 5, 6
```

How would I adjust this query so it returns 180 cell-results (that is, 90 rows) instead of 128 (64 rows)?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below

```
select 
  (case when grp_set & 1 > 0 then Reseller end) as Reseller,
  (case when grp_set & 2 > 0 then ProductGroup end) as ProductGroup,
  (case when grp_set & 4 > 0 then Product end) as Product,
  (case when grp_set & 8 > 0 then Year end) as Year,
  (case when grp_set & 16 > 0 then Quarter end) as Quarter,
  (case when grp_set & 32 > 0 then Product_Info end) as Product_Info,
  sum(Revenue) as Revenue,
  sum(Units) as Units    
from `first-outlet-750.biengine_tutorial.Product`, unnest(generate_array(1, 64)) grp_set
where Year IN (2020) and Quarter in ('Q1', 'Q2')
group by 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
having not (Quarter is null and Product_Info is not null)
and not (Year is null and Quarter is not null)
and not (ProductGroup is null and Product is not null)
order by 1, 2, 3, 4 , 5, 6
```

Comment: that gives us 360 results (180 rows) instead of 180 cells. I added in a handful of the `not (Reseller is null and ProductGroup is not null)...`'s.

Comment: oops, misread this one. looking again ...

Comment: see corrected answer

Comment: the idea here is to use only "filters" for naturally related dimensions - like Quarter must have a Year; Product must have a ProductGroup; looks like in your example ProductInfo depends on Quarter; So what should be remove is Reseller and ProductGroup  - there is no any natural dependency here - hope it makes sense :o)

Comment: awesome. Just asked another question about feasibility of turning it into a table function.