# Turning PIVOT query into table function

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Following up on [BigQuery pivot on more fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69805421/bigquery-pivot-on-more-fields), based on the suggestion by the genius Mikhail, I was wondering if the following 'pivot-like functionality' could be turned into a table function. Here would be an example:

[image]

The query from the currently accepted answer is:

```
select 
  (case when grp_set & 1 > 0 then Reseller end) as Reseller,
  (case when grp_set & 2 > 0 then ProductGroup end) as ProductGroup,
  (case when grp_set & 4 > 0 then Product end) as Product,
  (case when grp_set & 8 > 0 then Year end) as Year,
  (case when grp_set & 16 > 0 then Quarter end) as Quarter,
  (case when grp_set & 32 > 0 then Product_Info end) as Product_Info,
  sum(Revenue) as Revenue,
  sum(Units) as Units    
from `first-outlet-750.biengine_tutorial.Product`, unnest(generate_array(1, 64)) grp_set
where Year IN (2020) and Quarter in ('Q1', 'Q2')
group by 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
having not (Quarter is null and Product_Info is not null)
and not (Year is null and Quarter is not null)
and not (ProductGroup is null and Product is not null)
order by 1, 2, 3, 4 , 5, 6
```

And I'm wondering if a table function could be created along the lines of:

```
PIVOT(
    [row_agg1, row_agg2, ...], 
    [col_agg1, col_agg2, ...], 
    [agg_val1, agg_val2, ...]
)
```

So the above query could hopefully be translated into something like:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    PIVOT(
        [Reseller, ProductGroup, Product], -- rows
        [Year, Quarter, ProductInfo],      -- cols
        [SUM(Revenue), SUM(Units)]         -- vals
    )
```

A few things that I think might be a bit tricky:

- Where does the actual table go in the `FROM` clause?
- How would aliases work? For example, what if we wanted `SUM(Revenue)` to show up as `TotalRev` -- how to easily be able to refer to that in the main `SELECT` clause to be able to alias it if not just doing a `SELECT *` ?

Comment: I think this can qualify to submit as a feature request :o) Meantime, I did countless answers here on SO on that/related topic - search for `pivot`, `transpose`, etc. . Also see [Easy pivot() in BigQuery, in one step](https://hoffa.medium.com/easy-pivot-in-bigquery-one-step-5a1f13c6c710) by Felipe Hoffa

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant cool yea it's a good start but only allows a single col/rows.

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant 'feature request' for you to work on (i.e., paid -- if so can I send you an email)? Or a feature request to the bigquery team? I think the latter would probably not be accepted since this is such an esoteric not-very-set-based table function.

Comment: :o) Obviously, I meant feature request to BigQuery Team! Of course, you need to make good use case for them. I see this as a good one! I would be first to star it!  :o)

Comment: You can file a feature request in http://issuetracker.google.com/. For more details on creating a feature request you can refer to this [document](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#feature_requests).