# Workaround for multiple rollups

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, combinatorics, rollup

Is there a way to accomplish the following in BigQuery? This syntax is supported in a DB such as [Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/queries-table-expressions.html):

```
SELECT ProductGroup, Product, Year, Month, AVG(Revenue) 
FROM Sales
group by rollup(ProductGroup, Product), rollup(Year, Month)
```

In other words, I want the cross product of the two rollups:

```
ROLLUP(ProductGroup, Product) --> (), (ProductGroup), (ProductGroup, Product)
ROLLUP(Year, Month) --> (), (Year), (Year, Month)

((), (ProductGroup), (ProductGroup, Product)) x ((), (Year), (Year, Month))
= (
    (), (ProductGroup), (ProductGroup, Product),
    (Year), (Year, ProductGroup), (Year, ProductGroup, Product).
     (Year, Month), (Year, Month, ProductGroup), (Year, Month, ProductGroup, Product)
)
```

When attempting in BQ I get the following error:

> The GROUP BY clause only supports ROLLUP when there are no other grouping elements at [2:10]

---

**Here is an update with some sample pictures and data**.

First, I want to replicate the functionality of an Excel Pivot table.  This is where the cross product of the rollups from ROWS and COLS come into play:

[image]

Note that the Pivot table has 63 value cells.

Now, the correct SQL syntax for this is as follows in the verbose `GROUP BY`-only syntax:

[image]

Notice that this also produces exactly 63 rows (and since we have one value column -- SUM Revenue -- 63 rows x 1 col = 63 value cells). The query is the following:

```
with sales as (
    select 2010 Year, 'Jan' Month, 'Electronics' ProductGroup, 'Phone' Product, 100 Revenue union all
    select 2010,    'Jan',  'Electronics',  'Laptop',   200 union all
    select 2010,    'Jan',  'Cars', 'Jeep', 250 union all
    select 2010,    'Jan',  'Cars', 'Hummer',   105 union all
    select 2010,    'Feb',  'Electronics',  'Phone',    110 union all
    select 2010,    'Feb',  'Electronics',  'Laptop',   300 union all
    select 2010,    'Feb',  'Cars', 'Jeep', 50 union all
    select 2010,    'Feb',  'Cars', 'Hummer',   75 union all
    select 2010,    'Mar',  'Electronics',  'Phone',    80 union all
    select 2010,    'Mar',  'Electronics',  'Laptop',   200 union all
    select 2010,    'Mar',  'Cars', 'Jeep', 100 union all
    select 2010,    'Mar',  'Cars', 'Hummer',   50 union all
    select 2011,    'Jan',  'Electronics',  'Phone',    200 union all
    select 2011,    'Jan',  'Electronics',  'Laptop',   300 union all
    select 2011,    'Jan',  'Cars', 'Jeep', 100 union all
    select 2011,    'Jan',  'Cars', 'Hummer',   200 union all
    select 2011,    'Feb',  'Electronics',  'Phone',    300 union all
    select 2011,    'Feb',  'Electronics',  'Laptop',   900 union all
    select 2011,    'Feb',  'Cars', 'Jeep', 100 union all
    select 2011,    'Feb',  'Cars', 'Hummer',   200 union all
    select 2011,    'Mar',  'Electronics',  'Phone',    400 union all
    select 2011,    'Mar',  'Electronics',  'Laptop',   350 union all
    select 2011,    'Mar',  'Cars', 'Jeep', 240 union all
    select 2011,    'Mar',  'Cars', 'Hummer',   130
)
-- ROLLUP(ProductGroup, Product), ROLLUP(Year, Month)
--> (), (ProductGroup), (ProductGroup, Product)
--> (Year), (Year, ProductGroup), (Year, ProductGroup, Product)
--> (Year, Month), (Year, Month, ProductGroup), (Year, Month, ProductGroup, Product)

SELECT NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, AVG(Revenue) FROM Sales UNION ALL                                                -- ()
SELECT ProductGroup, NULL, NULL, NULL, AVG(Revenue) FROM Sales GROUP BY ProductGroup UNION ALL                  -- (ProductGroup)
SELECT ProductGroup, Product, NULL, NULL, AVG(Revenue) FROM Sales GROUP BY ProductGroup, Product UNION ALL      -- (ProductGroup, Product)

SELECT NULL, NULL, Year, NULL, AVG(Revenue) FROM Sales GROUP BY Year UNION ALL                                  -- (Year)
SELECT ProductGroup, NULL, Year, NULL, AVG(Revenue) FROM Sales GROUP BY Year, ProductGroup UNION ALL            -- (Year, ProductGroup)
SELECT ProductGroup, Product, Year, NULL, AVG(Revenue) FROM Sales GROUP BY Year, ProductGroup, Product UNION ALL-- (Year, ProductGroup, Product)

SELECT NULL, NULL, Year, Month, AVG(Revenue) FROM Sales GROUP BY Year, Month UNION ALL                          -- (Year, Month)
SELECT ProductGroup, NULL, Year, Month, AVG(Revenue) FROM Sales GROUP BY ProductGroup, Year, Month UNION ALL    -- (ProductGroup, Year, Month)
SELECT ProductGroup, Product, Year, Month, AVG(Revenue) FROM Sales GROUP BY ProductGroup, Product, Year, Month  -- (ProductGroup, Product, Year Month)
```

However, this query is really a nightmare to product -- even if generated programatically -- as there may be an `order by`, `subselect`, ... etc and union-ing all those statements together could potentially turn into a monstrous construction (for example, a 3 rows x 3 cols construction with a 100-line SQL statement would become 4^2 * 100 lines of sql, and 5x5 would be 5^2 * 100 lines, etc. if my math is correct).

What would be the proper way to do this then? Note that in a database like Postgres the following works as-is:

```
SELECT ProductGroup, Product, Year, Month, AVG(Revenue) FROM Sales GROUP BY ROLLUP(ProductGroup, Product), ROLLUP(Year, Month);
```

Here is the Saved Query if you want to use this as a starting point: https://console.cloud.google.com/bigquery?sq=260144861653:552549d2a81a47b59df6e3d16ef9bf17.

---

Finally, if you think it would be a useful feature to add in the `GROUPING SETS` and `CUBE`, please upvote this feature request: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/204913323.

Comment: 1) provide sample data and desired output. 2) also show us the whole query you got the error

Comment: but I don't think syntax like GROUP BY a, ROLLUP(b) is available in bigQuery

Comment: I can be wrong but - the query you presented is too abstract and does not have much sense so it is hard to help. can you adjust it to make it practical - like all fields from group by to be presented  in select and maybe some aggregation(s). ideally if you provide simplified example of input data and expected output :o)

Comment: Wouldn't that give a union rather than a cross product?

Comment: @shawnt00 added example data with use case.

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant added example data with use case.

Comment: @eshirvana added example data with use case.

Comment: @shawnt00 - in BigQuery `,` shortcut for `CROSS JOIN`

Comment: @David542 seems like you want to do `group by cube` which GBQ doesn't support it ( I could be wrong but couldn't find anything in google documentations)

Comment: @eshirvana yes it doesn't support it. It's not really group by cube. Cube gives all possible combinations but the above is just a cross-join on two rollups (i.e., it's impossible to have something like `GROUP BY ProductGroup, Month` -- as month would 'belong-to' a year and so could not be included in an aggregation **without** year, so it would only allow `GROUP BY ProductGroup, Year, Month` which the rollups control.

Comment: @David542 I think GBQ doesn't support `group by grouping sets` either . so that really sucks and you have to go with a combination of roll up and union  statements.

Comment: @eshirvana by the way, here is the saved query I have (thus far) -- https://console.cloud.google.com/bigquery?sq=260144861653:552549d2a81a47b59df6e3d16ef9bf17

Comment: @Mikhail That's not the way grouping sets work though.

Comment: @shawnt00 - BigQuery does not support grouping sets! so the focus of this post is to find workaround for `I want the cross product of the two rollups` ! as of use of `comma` I just replied on your `Wouldn't that give a union rather than a cross product?`

Comment: Are any of the grouping columns NULLable?  (Or do you ONLY ever get a NULL in those columns when they're rolled up?)

Comment: let's assume they're not null just for simpliity

Comment: @Mikhail My comment pertained to OP's opening paragraph regarding "a DB such as Postgres".

Comment: @shawnt00 - sorry if there was some misunderstanding during the back and forth on different aspects of this post :o)

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: I misread that `GROUP BY ROLLUP(A, B), C, D` was possible, here's an alternative.

You could implement your own `GROUPING SETS` logic by cross joining on to a map of which columns you want to rollup or not...

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN include_pg = 1 THEN ProductGroup END,
  CASE WHEN include_p  = 1 THEN Product      END,
  CASE WHEN include_y  = 1 THEN Year         END,
  CASE WHEN include_m  = 1 THEN Month        END,
  AVG(Revenue)
FROM
  Sales
CROSS JOIN
(
              SELECT 1 AS include_pg, 1 AS include_p
    UNION ALL SELECT 1 AS include_pg, 0 AS include_p
    UNION ALL SELECT 0 AS include_pg, 0 AS include_p
)
  AS rollup_pg_p
CROSS JOIN
(
              SELECT 1 AS include_y, 1 AS include_m
    UNION ALL SELECT 1 AS include_y, 0 AS include_m
    UNION ALL SELECT 0 AS include_y, 0 AS include_m
)
  AS rollup_y_m
GROUP BY
  1, 2, 3, 4
ORDER BY
  1, 2, 3, 4
```

Comment: this, unfortunately, will not work in BigQuery and will fail with exactly same error as OP mentioned in his question

Comment: @Mat -- I included a public query link with all the data in the question, but here is it i f you want to test it on BQ: https://console.cloud.google.com/bigquery?sq=260144861653:552549d2a81a47b59df6e3d16ef9bf17.

Comment: @Mat -- in the case of a derive-able calculation such as AVG this works, but also consider the case of something like `COUNT DISTINCT`, `MEDIAN`, etc.

Comment: @David542 - If you need those, they should be in your question.   SO is not the place for abstract questions, it relies on concrete examples.

Comment: @MatBailie agreed. I was just pointing that out for this sort of technique -- that can often be applied for something like a `AVG` but not something like a `MED`.

Comment: @David542 - New answer, which should work for any arbitrary aggregate.  In this case it processes 6x as much data and obstructs use of indexes, etc, so may be slightly cleaner, but with worse performance.

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant - Does BigQuery have an equivalent to `sales CROSS APPLY (SELECT sales.a, sales.b UNION ALL SELET sales.a, NULL UNION ALL SELECT NULL, NULL)`?

Comment: no equivalent - but same can be achieved - I think there are some/few posts on this subject I already answered with possible solutions

Answer (score 1):

ugly but probably the simplest way to have 3 group by statement and union them :

```
SELECT ProductGroup,Product,NULL year ,NULL month, AVG(sales.Revenue) avg  
FROM sales 
GROUP BY ROLLUP(ProductGroup,Product)

UNION DISTINCT
SELECT ProductGroup,Product,Year,NULL month, AVG(sales.Revenue) avg  
FROM sales 
GROUP BY ROLLUP(Year, ProductGroup, Product)

UNION DISTINCT 
SELECT ProductGroup,Product,Year,MONTH, AVG(sales.Revenue) avg  
FROM sales 
GROUP BY ROLLUP(Year, Month, ProductGroup, Product)
```

[GCP fiddle](https://console.cloud.google.com/bigquery?project=massive-plasma-306700&ws=!1m4!1m3!8m2!1s675092128702!2s58f74d2cf8914e99b04def842298b692&j=bq:US:bquxjob_7908901_17cec9b0820&page=queryresults)

Comment: I think in that case you only need three: `ROLLUP(ProductGroup, Product)`, `ROLLUP(Year, ProductGroup, Product)`, `ROLLUP(Year, Month, ProductGroup, Product)`. And the only 'overlap' is on the `()` in all three.

Comment: @David542 right , right which with can omit over laps by `union distinct`

Comment: looks like we are back to your very original post - https://stackoverflow.com/q/69804322/5221944   :o)

Comment: I don't think I am right person to ask such questions! you can make feature request to BigQuery Team

Comment: @eshirvana you can upvote this feature request I added: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/204913323.

Comment: Rather than `UNION DISTINCT`, would it be preferable to add `HAVING ProductGroup IS NOT NULL OR Product IS NOT NULL` to the first two queries?  *(To exlude the `()` group from those two queries.)*  That would allow a simple `UNION ALL`?

Answer (score 1):

> it gives the correct number of rows but how would I pass along the AVG(Revenue)?

Consider below - looks like a simple pattern to apply to more of your potential cases

```
select r.Year, r.Month, r.ProductGroup, r.Product, 
  round(avg(Revenue), 2) avg_Revenue
from (
  select * from (
    select ProductGroup, Product from Sales group by rollup(ProductGroup, Product)
  ), (
    select Year, Month from Sales group by rollup(Year, Month)
  )
) r 
join sales s
on if(r.Year is null, true, r.Year = s.Year) 
and if(r.Month is null, true, r.Month = s.Month) 
and if(r.ProductGroup is null, true, r.ProductGroup = s.ProductGroup)
and if(r.Product is null, true, r.Product = s.Product) 
group by r.Year, r.Month, r.ProductGroup, r.Product
```

if applied to sample data in your script - output is (cut by top rows)

[image]

Comment: @mikahil -- cool approach thanks for this. Though so far in the examples I've seen I think the cleanest (unfortunately) is the multiple UNION'ed ROLLUPs.

Comment: sure, agree, while having more working approaches is always better than just one :o) I usually trying  to keep posts warm even if already accepted answer to bring my own experience and approaches. in any case i think my answers were/are helpful at some extend :o)  agree?

Answer (score 1):

Similar to my previous answer, but without `CASE` expressions 'blocking' use of indexes.

It still processes 9x as much data though, but probably more quickly than the `CASE` based approach.

```
WITH
  rollup_pg_p AS
(
            SELECT ProductGroup, Product, Year, Month, Revenue FROM Sales 
  UNION ALL SELECT ProductGroup, NULL,    Year, Month, Revenue FROM Sales 
  UNION ALL SELECT NULL,         NULL,    Year, Month, Revenue FROM Sales 
),
  rollup_y_m AS
(
            SELECT ProductGroup, Product, Year, Month, Revenue FROM rollup_pg_p
  UNION ALL SELECT ProductGroup, Product, Year, NULL,  Revenue FROM rollup_pg_p
  UNION ALL SELECT ProductGroup, Product, NULL, NULL,  Revenue FROM rollup_pg_p
)
SELECT
  ProductGroup, Product, Year, Month, AVG(Revenue) FROM rollup_y_m
GROUP BY
  1, 2, 3, 4
ORDER BY
  1, 2, 3, 4
```

**Edit: An elaboration.**

Your query is this *(`-` is my shorthand for `NULL` in pseudocode)*...

```
          SELECT a, b, c, d, AVG(x) FROM src GROUP BY a, b, c, d
UNION ALL SELECT a, b, c, -, AVG(x) FROM src GROUP BY a, b, c
UNION ALL SELECT a, b, -, -, AVG(x) FROM src GROUP BY a, b

UNION ALL SELECT a, -, c, d, AVG(x) FROM src GROUP BY a, c, d
UNION ALL SELECT a, -, c, -, AVG(x) FROM src GROUP BY a, c
UNION ALL SELECT a, -, -, -, AVG(x) FROM src GROUP BY a

UNION ALL SELECT -, -, c, d, AVG(x) FROM src GROUP BY c, d
UNION ALL SELECT -, -, c, -, AVG(x) FROM src GROUP BY c
UNION ALL SELECT -, -, -, -, AVG(x) FROM src
```

Which is functionally the same as this...

```
WITH
  combinations AS (
              SELECT a, b, c, d, x FROM src
    UNION ALL SELECT a, b, c, -, x FROM src
    UNION ALL SELECT a, b, -, -, x FROM src
    
    UNION ALL SELECT a, -, c, d, x FROM src
    UNION ALL SELECT a, -, c, -, x FROM src
    UNION ALL SELECT a, -, -, -, x FROM src
    
    UNION ALL SELECT -, -, c, d, x FROM src
    UNION ALL SELECT -, -, c, -, x FROM src
    UNION ALL SELECT -, -, -, -, x FROM src
)
SELECT a, b, c, d, AVG(x) FROM combinations GROUP BY a, b, c, d
```

The advantage of the latter is that the aggregate (or aggregates) that you want to apply are only written once, as is the `GROUP BY`.

This still requires enumerating all 9 combinations.

So, the answer at the start is just a short hand way of enumerating the 9 combinations.  Not much shorter, but slightly.  And would be even more valuable if you needed `ROLLUP(a, b), ROLLUP(c, d), ROLLUP(e, f)` *(Writing 3 combinations for each `ROLLUP()`, for 9 in total, to generate 27 combinations.)*

Comment: very interesting approach, can you explain how this works briefly with the two cte's?

Comment: @David Both of my my answers are the same as your answer, but expressed differently; ways of creating the 9 different combinations of aggregation you want.  This answer creates 3 combinations of the raw data in the first CTE, and then 3 combination from the CTE, giving the 9 total combinations over the raw data.  Then aggregates once.

Answer (score 1):

Back to my original answer of grouping twice...

```
WITH
  rollup_pg_p AS
(
  SELECT
    ProductGroup, Product, 1 AS dummy, Year, Month, SUM(Revenue) AS sum_rev, COUNT(Revenue) AS cnt_row
  FROM
    Sales
  GROUP BY
    ROLLUP(Year, Month, ProductGroup, Product)
  HAVING
    Month IS NOT NULL -- This prevents the roll up going further than desired
                      -- Effectively giving `GROUP BY Year, Month, ROLLUP(ProductGroup, Product)
)
SELECT
  ProductGroup, Product, Year, Month, SUM(sum_rev) / SUM(cnt_row)
FROM
  rollup_pg_p
GROUP BY
  ROLLUP(ProductGroup, Product, Dummy, Year, Month)
HAVING
  dummy IS NOT NULL -- Same 'trick' again, but we created the dummy column
                    -- as ProductGroup and Product CAN legitimately be NULL at this point.
ORDER BY
  1, 2, 3, 4
```

*(NOTE: Other dialects would use `WHERE NOT GROUPING(Product)`, so avoid the need for the dummy column, but BigQuery doesn't appear to have that functionality either...)*

Still has the downside of not working for some aggregates, but ***might*** be meaningfully faster than the alternative approaches.

Answer (score 0):

> I want the cross product of the two rollups:

Consider below

```
select * from (
select date, code 
from `first-outlet-750.tests.parq_stored`
group by rollup(date, code)
), (
select country, state 
from `first-outlet-750.tests.parq_stored`
group by rollup(country, state))
```

with output like below

[image]

Comment: please see updated question with examples and all.

Comment: does my current answer address your initial question, so you can apply it to your specific use case?

Comment: it gives the correct number of rows but how would I pass along the `AVG(Revenue)` ?

Comment: here is a link to the query: https://console.cloud.google.com/bigquery?sq=260144861653:552549d2a81a47b59df6e3d16ef9bf17

Comment: I will look further into this shortly (at next available time spot) :o) meantime, looks like we half-way there already

Comment: Additionally, I added this feature request: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/204913323. Please star that if you think it'd be useful.